# unknown encoding nameが表示される

Tags: ruby, windows

rubyinstaller-devkit-2.7.2-1-x64からRubyをインストールし、`ruby -v` を実行すると以下の表示がされます。

```
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]
```

しかし、それ以外(gemのインストールなど)を実行しようとすると以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last): ruby.exe: unknown encoding name -
utf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-U
(RuntimeError)
```

Rubyインストール時に「use utf-8 as default～」にはチェックを入れてインストールしています。

何が問題なのでしょうか。解決方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

PCはwindow10,64bitです。

Comment: `ruby -v` や "gem のインストール" などはそれぞれどのように実行していますか？ (コマンドプロンプトを使っている等)

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで実行しています。他のPCで同じようにインストールすると普通に実行できるので、PCの問題なのでしょうか。

Comment: 他のプログラムが未だUTF-8に対応していないとか？ いったんUTF-8指定の`RUBYOPT`を削除してみるとか、RUBY自身の版数を上げてみるとか。[「Ruby 2.7」に対応した「RubyInstaller」が登場 ～「Ruby」を手軽にWindows環境へ導入](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1227909.html), [「Ruby 3.0」に対応した「RubyInstaller」が公開 ～UTF-8への移行も完了](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1298434.html)

Comment: RUBYOPTを削除して、rubyを再インストールすると上手く作動しました！ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Rubyやインストールしようとしたgemの問題ではありません。

```
C:\>set RUBYOPT=-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-U

C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x64-mingw32]

C:\>ruby
Traceback (most recent call last):
ruby: unknown encoding name - utf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-Eutf-8;-U (RuntimeError)
```

のように、何らかの理由でそのPCに不正な`RUBYOPT`環境変数が設定されていたのだと思います。